# reassigning elements of a dict which uses both a string and a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to reassign elements of my dict but coming up with a problem:

```
name  = "none"
scripts = "blank"
stats = {"hp" : 0, "sp" :0}
atk = {"normal": 0, "crit" : 0, "crit chance": 0}
sword = {"attack": atk, "scripts" : scripts}
actions = {"melee" : sword}
blank = {"name" : "blank", "stats" : stats, "action" : actions}

attacker = blank

scripts = {"normal 1" : "%s attacks with %s
         (attacker["name"],attacker["action"]["melee"]["attack"]["normal"])}
stats = {"hp" : 20, "sp" :5}
atk = {"normal": 12, "crit" : 15, "crit chance": 30}
sword = {"attack": atk, "scripts" : scripts}
actions = {"melee" : sword}
character = {"name" : "Jabe", "stats" : stats, "action" : actions}

attacker = character


print (attacker["action"]["melee"]["scripts"]["normal 1"])
print (attacker["action"]["melee"]["attack"])
```

in my turn based game I have a loop where first the player attacks then the enemy attacks, so I don't have to write the same code again, initially the attacker = the player's character and the enemy = attacked, but after its run through the players combat the player then becomes the attacked then the enemy becomes the attacker so the contents of the dict needs to change, which works mostly, until you get to the "script" bit.

for my game to work I want the above code to output the script from "character" using its values for the dict elements it calls from, like this:

```
Jabe attacks with 12
```

but instead it outputs:

```
blank attacks with 0
```

Comment: please provide code that works. More likely to get a helpful response with a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various way you can attach some code to data.  One was is to make a [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) and call it to build the string you want to print:

#### Code:

```
scripts = {"normal 1": lambda x: "{} attacks with {}".format(
    x["name"], x["action"]["melee"]["attack"]["normal"])}
```

and then:

```
print(attacker["action"]["melee"]["scripts"]["normal 1"](attacker))
```

An aside: The below works, but a better way to do this sort of thing is to use [objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

#### All of it:

```
name = "none"
scripts = "blank"
stats = {"hp": 0, "sp": 0}
atk = {"normal": 0, "crit": 0, "crit chance": 0}
sword = {"attack": atk, "scripts": scripts}
actions = {"melee": sword}
blank = {"name": "blank", "stats": stats, "action": actions}

attacker = blank

scripts = {"normal 1": lambda x: "{} attacks with {}".format(
    x["name"], x["action"]["melee"]["attack"]["normal"])}
stats = {"hp": 20, "sp": 5}
atk = {"normal": 12, "crit": 15, "crit chance": 30}
sword = {"attack": atk, "scripts": scripts}
actions = {"melee": sword}
character = {"name": "Jabe", "stats": stats, "action": actions}

attacker = character

print(attacker["action"]["melee"]["scripts"]["normal 1"](attacker))
print(attacker["action"]["melee"]["attack"])
```

#### Results:

```
Jabe attacks with 12
{'crit': 15, 'crit chance': 30, 'normal': 12}
```